# Prevent table from resizing when adding border to specific cell

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my code. The problem is: When i click a td cell, add border to it, and the border makes the table changes size.

For some reasons, i dont want the table increase its size when adding border to td tag, and i can not use outline in css.

I tried to add this line of css code : **box-sizing: border-box;** but it does not seem to work.

Thank you for any idea!!

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('td'),
  function(td) {
    td.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.target.classList.add('myBorder')
    })
  })
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.myBorder {
  border: 2px solid #4b89ff;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Bob</td>
      <td>Male</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Anna</td>
      <td>Female</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Christ</td>
      <td>Male</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: .myBorder for this class border should be 1px instead of 2px

Comment: Give all the cells the same border of 1 pixel no color, then when visualize it, you give the border a color, no change in layout.

Comment: @VikasJadhav the expectation of this border is 2px of width unfortunately :(

Comment: @Grumpy could you tell me more clearly, or answer below in this post, please?

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the **td** with Chrome i found that adding the class to the cell was also generating a padding of 1px. And if you set `padding-bottom: 0px;` on .myBorder class will solve the problem.

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('td'),
  function(td) {
    td.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.target.classList.add('myBorder')
    })
  })
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.myBorder {
  border: 2px solid #4b89ff;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Bob</td>
      <td>Male</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Anna</td>
      <td>Female</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Christ</td>
      <td>Male</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It works, but as i wrote in the question, i can not use outline.

Comment: Im sorry my bad, didn't noticed in the question. Why you can't?

Comment: because the css:outline can not be set in specific position like border, ex: i can use border-top, but not outline-top. the purpose of outline is all or nothing, so that i have to use border instead of outline

Comment: Check the updated answer, i've added another method.

Comment: Sorry, ignore it. With 2px it doesn't work, just noticed.

Comment: thank you for sharing, maybe the format of border in table does not support this.

Comment: WOW i got a bit mad to find what was the problem ahah. Check the updated answer :)

Comment: hmm i dont think the problem is the padding.. Have you tried clicking each cell in the table by turn? Test this case, i click in order: 1 > Bob > Male > 2 > Anna > Female > 3, it seems work perfectly, but if i continue clicking Christ > Male, the border goes wrong.. I really don't know what the hell is going on >.<

Comment: Well, then you have to set a fix padding for the cell. Because if you set the padding to "padding: 0px" once you click the text will be moved up by 1 px.
But if you set on td padding 3px then with myBorder you set it on 1px with 2px border will be fine.